# Spring security with login with amazon

Tags: spring-security, facebook-login, spring-security-oauth2

We had an application that uses basic auth (user and password), we created the roles in the Database and it worked perfectly.
Now we are migrating to use Login With Amazon and we will also add Login With Facebook.
Is there an easy way to keep our current Spring Security architecture (I do not need the user password anymore though, I would like to keep the roles) and add support to Login With Amazon.

I noticed there is this project for Spring Security with oAuth2 http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/ It is not clear to me what this does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for Spring oAuth is pretty bad, but the [examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2) they provide are workable if you know your way around Spring Security.

I want to to flag here that using oAuth 2 for user authentication [isn't recommended](http://oauth.net/articles/authentication/) and that you should stick to providers that support Open ID Connect. It is not clear to me from a quick glance at Login With Amazon if it's OIDC or just plain oAuth2, but either way you can use their SDK to achieve what you're looking for.

It is definitely possible to use Spring oAuth to set up login over oAuth 2, and probably OIDC as well, but I always end up rolling my own solution because I find it simpler.

I'm going to focus on Login with Amazon here, but login with Facebook should be fairly similar.

There are four things you need to do:

1. Add Amazon login to your website
2. Implement support for storing a user's external ID in the user profile
3. Implement a controller for handling JWT tokens and "logging in" the user
4. Call the new controller once the user has logged in

The first one should be fairly easy and is detailed in [Amazon's documentation](http://login.amazon.com/website)

The second one is entirely up to you since it depends on your database solution, but if you're limiting yourself to one or two providers the easiest way is probably to just add the attribute *amazonId* to the user profile.

The third one will look something like this:

```
@Controller
public class OidcController {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @RequestMapping("/login/amazon")
    public String handleAmazonOidc(@RequestParam String access_token) {
        // verify that the access token belongs to us
        Content c = Request.Get("https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/tokeninfo?access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode(access_token, "UTF-8"))
                       .execute()
                       .returnContent();

        Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)objectMapper.readValue(c.toString(), Map.class);
        if (!"YOUR-CLIENT-ID".equals(m.get("aud"))) {
            // the access token does not belong to us
            throw new InvalidTokenException("Invalid token");
        }

        // Get the user ID from Amazon and get the corresponding user on our end
        m = new ObjectMapper().readValue(c.toString(), new TypeReference>(){});
        String amazonUserId = m.get("user_id");

        User user = getUserFromAmazonId(amazonUserId);
        if (user == null) {
            // User needs to register first
            return "redirect:/register";
        }

        // Authenticate the user in the current security context
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken token = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(user, token, user.getAuthorities());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);

        // Redirect the user to the front page
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Fourth one is easy, just redirect the user in the callback in the UI:

```
amazon.Login.authorize(options, 'https://www.example.com/login/amazon');
```

Now, you're in some trouble since you've already got users in the database that hasn't got an Amazon user ID to look for so you'll probably have to run both authentication schemes in parallel for a while and allow users to connect with Amazon while they're logged in with username and password. Modifying the above controller to insert the Amazon user ID in the current user profile instead of setting it in the security context should be fairly straightforward though.

Comment: Thanks lot for your reply Raniz. in this line 

PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken token = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(user, token, user.getAuthorities());

How did you figure out we need PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken ? Is there some good doc/examples around that class.
 I think this is exactly what I was looking for. The second parameter is token, did you mean the oAuTh access token? Should I just pass null there.

Comment: One Small thing, what is the problem of using oAuth for authentication. In this case, if I don't, what is the right way of authenticating? (I am not planning to use user/password, only login with amazon)

Comment: The problem is this: "Since an authentication usually occurs ahead of the issuance of an access token, it is tempting to consider reception of an access token of any type proof that such an authentication has occurred." Just getting an access token isn't proof that the user was involved when the access token was issued - it could have been issued with a refresh token in which case the user is not present. an ID token from OIDC contains information you can use to verify that the user was present. Read the *Common Pitfalls* section (and the next about OIDC) of the article I linked to for more